# Reassign entire array to the same reference

Tags: ruby

I've searched extensively but sadly couldn't find a solution to this surely often-asked question.
In Perl I can reassign an entire array within a function and have my changes reflected outside the function:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use v5.20;
use Data::Dumper;

sub foo {
    my ($ref) = @_;
    @$ref = (3, 4, 5);
}
my $ref = [1, 2];
foo($ref);
say Dumper $ref;    # prints [3, 4, 5]
```

Now I'm trying to learn Ruby and have written a function where I'd like to change an array `items` in-place by filtering out elements matching a condition and returning the removed items:

```rb
def filterItems(items)
  removed, items = items.partition { ... }
```

After running the function, `items` returns to its state before calling the function. How should I approach this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to change an array items in-place by filtering out elements matching a condition and returning the removed items [...] How should I approach this please?

You could [`replace`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-replace) the array content within your method:

```
def filter_items(items)
  removed, kept = items.partition { |i| i.odd? }
  items.replace(kept)
  removed
end

ary = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

filter_items(ary)
#=> [1, 3, 5]

ary
#=> [2, 4]
```

Comment: be aware of time spent on debugging "who mutated items?"

Comment: ...or `items[0..-1] = kept`.

Answer (score 0):

I would search for `pass by value/reference in ruby`. Here is one I found first https://mixandgo.com/learn/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value. 
You pass reference value of `items` to the function, not the reference to `items`. Variable `items` is defined out of method scope and always refers to same value, unless you reassign it in the variable scope.

Also `filterItems` is not ruby style, see https://rubystyle.guide/

Comment: I don't think that's correct. If I just reassign one element of the array, then `items` will change:
`def filter_items(items);  items[0] = 100; end; items = [1, 2]; filter_items(items); p items    # prints [100, 2]`

Comment: my fault, there is another option to search `ruby mutating/non mutating` and it should give you https://launchschool.com/blog/mutating-and-non-mutating-methods. `partition` method does not mutate and assigning array's value mutates the array

Comment: True, thanks for finding these articles. I'll amend my question to ask if anybody wrote a function to work around this default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

To access or modify an outer variable within a block, declare the variable outside the block. To access a variable outside of a method, store it in an instance or class variable. There's a lot more to it than that, but this covers the use case in your original post.

### Explanation and Examples

In Ruby, you have scope gates and closures. In particular, methods and blocks represent scope gates, but there are certainly ways (both routine and meta) for accessing variables outside of your local scope.

In a class, this is usually handled by instance variables. So, as a simple example of [String#parition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-partition) (because it's easier to explain than [Enumerable#partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) on an Array):

```
def filter items, separator
  head, sep, tail = items.partition separator
  @items = tail
end

filter "foobarbaz", "bar"
#=> "baz"

@items
#=> "baz"
```

Inside a class or within irb, this will modify whatever's passed and then assign it to the instance variable outside the method.

### Partitioning Arrays Instead of Strings

If you really don't want to pass things as arguments, or if *@items* should be an Array, then you can certainly do that too. However, Arrays behave differently, so I'm not sure what you really expect Array#partition (which is inherited from Enumerable) to yield. This works, using [Enumerable#slice_after](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_after):

```
class Filter
  def initialize
    @items = []
  end

  def filter_array items, separator
    @items = [3,4,5].slice_after { |i| i == separator }.to_a.pop
  end
end

f = Filter.new
f.filter_array [3, 4, 5], 4
#=> [5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the **[Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html)** class for any method which mutates the object, for example all the method with a bang or methods that insert elements.

---

Here is an [Array#push](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21):

```
ary = [1,2,3,4,5]

def foo(ary)
  ary.push *[6, 7]
end

foo(ary)
ary
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

---

Here is an [Array#insert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-insert):

```
ary = [1,2,3,4,5]

def baz(ary)
  ary.insert(2, 10, 20)
end

baz(ary)
ary
#=> [1, 2, 10, 20, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

Here is an example with a **bang** [Array#reject!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21):

```
ary = [1,2,3,4,5]

def zoo(ary)
  ary.reject!(&:even?)
end

zoo(ary)
ary
#=> [1, 3, 5]
```

---

Another with a bang [Array#map!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21):

```
ary = [1,2,3,4,5]

def bar(ary)
  ary.map! { |e| e**2 }
end

bar(ary)
ary
#=> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```